# Create a way to stop to many duplicate values coming up in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have the following code for a JTable.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
///////////
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
///////////
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SelectTeam
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Select Team");
    
    JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel(); //a panel for first tab

    //first panel components
    JScrollPane myScrollTable;
    JTextField filterAthID;
    JTextField filterForeName;
    TableRowSorter sorter;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JLabel AthleteID = new JLabel();
    JLabel ForeName = new JLabel();
    JTable athTable;
    JComboBox bPartInEventCB;
    int nextPosition=0;
    
    public void runGUI()
    {       
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 1296, 756); //set position, then dimensions
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        
        createFirstPanel(); //call method to create each panel
        
        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel); //adds the tabbedpane to mainWindow
        
        myMainWindow.setVisible(true); //make the GUI appear
        myMainWindow.setResizable(false);
    }
    
    public void createFirstPanel()
    {
        firstPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        AthleteID.setLocation(200,120); //Sets the location
        AthleteID.setSize(150,26); //Sets the size
        AthleteID.setText("Athlete ID Search:");
        firstPanel.add(AthleteID); //Adds it to the panel
        
        ForeName.setLocation(731,120); //Sets the location
        ForeName.setSize(150,26); //Sets the size
        ForeName.setText("Athlete Name Search:");
        firstPanel.add(ForeName); //Adds it to the panel
        
        String[] aHeaders = {"Athlete ID","Forename","Surname","On The Team"};
        String[][] sampleData = new String[10][4];
        
        sampleData[0][0]= "JS98";
        sampleData[0][1]= "John";
        sampleData[0][2]= "Smith";
        sampleData[0][3]= "Yes";
        
        sampleData[1][0]= "DB83";
        sampleData[1][2]= "David";
        sampleData[1][2]= "Bowser";
        sampleData[1][3]= "No";
        
        sampleData[2][0]= "TR68";
        sampleData[2][3]= "Trevor";
        sampleData[2][2]= "Radner";
        sampleData[2][3]= "No";
        
        sampleData[3][0]= "JR97";
        sampleData[3][4]= "Jon";
        sampleData[3][2]= "Raynor";
        sampleData[3][3]= "Yes";
        
        sampleData[4][0]= "AF11";
        sampleData[4][5]= "Adam";
        sampleData[4][2]= "Fawcett";
        sampleData[4][3]= "Yes";
        
        sampleData[5][0]= "ES96";
        sampleData[5][6]= "Emma";
        sampleData[5][2]= "Spender";
        sampleData[5][3]= "Yes";
        
        sampleData[6][0]= "GF56";
        sampleData[6][7]= "Gerald";
        sampleData[6][2]= "Fits";
        sampleData[6][3]= "No";
        
        sampleData[7][0]= "NC70";
        sampleData[7][8]= "Nicola";
        sampleData[7][2]= "Condron";
        sampleData[7][3]= "Yes";
        
        sampleData[8][0]= "SI25";
        sampleData[8][9]= "Sir";
        sampleData[8][2]= "Ivan";
        sampleData[8][3]= "Yes";
        
        sampleData[9][0]= "LH56";
        sampleData[9][10]= "Lord";
        sampleData[9][2]= "Hammerlock";
        sampleData[9][3]= "Yes";
        
        model = new DefaultTableModel(sampleData,aHeaders)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) 
            {
                if (column < 3) 
                {
                    return false;
                } 
                
                else 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
        athTable = new JTable(model);
        athTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        athTable.setRowHeight(20);
        
        myScrollTable = new JScrollPane(athTable); 
        myScrollTable.setSize(1082,600); 
        myScrollTable.setLocation(200,145); 
        System.out.println("Creating compare table");
        
        TableColumn sportColumn = athTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        bPartInEventCB = new JComboBox();
        bPartInEventCB.addItem("Yes");
        bPartInEventCB.addItem("No");
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(bPartInEventCB));
        
        sorter = new TableRowSorter(athTable.getModel());
        List sortKeys = new ArrayList();
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(3, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        athTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
        
        filterAthID = new JTextField(10);
        filterAthID.setSize(425,26); 
        filterAthID.setLocation(306,120);
        filterAthID.setToolTipText("Enter Athlete ID");
        firstPanel.add(filterAthID);
        
        filterForeName = new JTextField(10);
        filterForeName.setSize(425,26); 
        filterForeName.setLocation(857,120);
        filterForeName.setToolTipText("Enter Athlete Name");
        firstPanel.add(filterForeName);
        
        Document doc = filterAthID.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        doc.addDocumentListener(listener);
    
        Document docb = filterForeName.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listenerb = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        docb.addDocumentListener(listenerb);
        
        for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(athTable.getModel().getValueAt(i,0));
        }
        
        firstPanel.add(myScrollTable);
    }
    
    private void newFilter()
    {
        RowFilter rf = null;
        try 
        {
            List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterAthID.getText(), 0));
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterForeName.getText(), 1));
            rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
            
            List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filtersb = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
            filtersb.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterForeName.getText(), 1));
            filtersb.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterForeName.getText(), 2));
            rf = RowFilter.orFilter(filtersb);
        } 
        catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) 
        {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SelectTeam st = new SelectTeam();
        st.runGUI();
    }
}
```

It creates a table which looks like this.

[image: Table looks like this]

I would like to be able make it so if there are more than 8 values of "Yes" in the last column a popup comes up `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please remove a athlete from the team");` My only problem is I am unable to do this since I don't know how. I would appreciate any help in doing this.

Thanks

Edit

So I have added the following code

```
JButton btnUpdate = new JButton();

btnUpdate.setLocation(0,120);
btnUpdate.setSize(200,50);
btnUpdate.setText("Update the team");
btnUpdate.addActionListener(this);
firstPanel.add(btnUpdate);

public void checkCount(TableModel model) 
    {
        int count=0;
        for (int row=0; row<model.getRowCount(); row++) 
        {
            if ("Yes".equals(model.getValueAt(row, 3)))
            {
            count++;
            }
        }
      
        if (count>8)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please remove a athlete from the team");
        }
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == btnUpdate)
        {
            checkCount();
        }
    }
```

However when I compile this i get this error

[image: Error]

So what argument would I pass to make this work?

Comment: It would depend on how you are adding rows to the table

Comment: @MadProgrammer normally it would automatically add a row to the table every time a row in a text document is added. This is done via a different program

Comment: What I would consider doing, is overriding the `addRow` method of the `DefaultTableModel` and show how reject any row which doesn't meet your requirements, the problem with this, is the `addRow` already has a defined signature, which makes it difficult to provide notification to the caller. In this case I would use a `AbstractTableModel` as a base and provide your own `addRow` method, which could either return a `boolean` or throw an `Exception` of some kind.  I would also keep count of the number of "yes"s you have, rather then re-iterating the model each time

Comment: @MadProgrammer this is probably a simple answer but which argument would I pass?

Comment: Its okay worked it out

Comment: @Dan note usage of RowFilter/Sorter at runtime required convert index from view to model, I'd be use that in all cases, described in Oracle tutorial, tons posts here about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the TableModel counting the yes value from the last column. After that compare the counter with 8 and show the message if necessary.

Like this (is not tested)

```
public void checkCount(TableModel model) {
  int count=0;
  for (int row=0; row<model.getRowCount(); row++) {
    if ("Yes".equals(model.getValueAt(row, 3)) {
        count++;
    }
  }
  if (count>8) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please remove a athlete from the team");
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI this is rather in efficient, as you'd need to do this for each new row. It wild be better to extend from from AbstractTableModel and place the management within it, so it could reject any rows which fail to meet the requirements. This way, each time a row is updated or added, you could keep track of the number of yes/no answers

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would appreciate your expertise for help on another question, [Resizing JFrame in one dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133683/resizing-jframe-in-one-dimension)